# Copy & Paste Non-Contiguous Range Based on Criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I need to select a range of data in column Q that meet criteria found in column A (specifically, I wish to select only those cells which correspond to non-"" values in column A). The resulting range of selected cells will be non-contiguous.

I then want to copy these cells and paste their values in column K. The pasted values should retain the same row references as the copied range; basically, I'm just taking the values in the copied range and pasting the values x many columns to the left.

The problem I'm encountering is that it seems to only copy the final value in column Q and then paste this value in column K. So, I seem to be getting it to paste in the right place, but it's not copying the way I want it to.

The code I've written can be found below.

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub NonConRngPaste()
  
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rRng As Range
    Dim r As Range
    Dim pasteRng As Range

        For Each rCell In Range("A1:A1000")
            If rCell.Value <> "" Then
                If rRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set rRng = rCell
                Else
                    Set rRng = Application.Union(rRng, rCell)
                End If
            End If
        Next

        Set pasteRng = rRng.Offset(0, 10)
        For Each r In rRng.Offset(0, 16).Cells
            pasteRng.Value = r.Value
        Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: `r.Offset(0, -6).Value = r.Value`?

Answer (score 0):

May as well be simpler?

```vb
Sub NonConRngPaste()
   Dim c As Range
   Application.Screenupdating =  False
   For Each c In Range("A1:A1000").cells
        If len(c.value) > 0 Then
            with c.EntireRow
                .Columns("K").Value = .Columns("Q").Value 
            end with
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```